# How can I change URL of browser address bar without page refresh, remaining on same page?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to play background music without breaks. Change in URL( for example index.php?step1 ) refreshes my **index.php** page, even I reamin on index.php. please help me how can I prevent my index page from refreshing or playing music without breaks.

in **index.php**

```
<audio  controls preload="auto" >
<source src="bak_music/back_music.mp3"  ></source>
</audio>

 <a href="?step1">step 1</a>

    <?php 
    if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=='step1')
    {
    step1_function();
    }
    ?>
```

**refresh the my index.php**

Comment: There is no way to do precisely what you are indicating. Since you are using php to render content, you will need to refresh the entire page, or set up a new endpoint to request via ajax through javascript that provides whatever content you need. That said, your question is pretty broad as-is, and you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do what I'm thinking you can use Javascript and do an AJAX call to separate PHP code and return data where needed.

Something like this.

index.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="step-button" name="step1">Step 1</a>
<a href="#" class="step-button" name="step2">Step 2</a>

<script>

$(document).ready( function(){

    $('.step-button').click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();

        var step = $(this).attr('name');

        var postData = {
            step: step,
            action: 'stepFuntion',
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: step,
            success: function( data )
            {
                // Data to return
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    })

})

</script>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

if ( isset($_REQUEST['stepFuntion']) )
{

    $function = call_user_func( $_REQUEST['step'].'_function()' );
    $return = json_encode( $function );

    die($return);
}

?>
```

I think this will get you the result you want.